# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space GoogleAppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Got an application running on AppEngine. Has been running fine for 2 years. Checked in on it today and I discoverd it was failing. I have not touch the code for a long time.

The error I get is this:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.OnestoreEntity$Property.<init>(OnestoreEntity.java:2849)
at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.OnestoreEntity$EntityProto.addProperty(OnestoreEntity.java:5755)
at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.OnestoreEntity$EntityProto.merge(OnestoreEntity.java:6232)
at com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$QueryResult.merge(DatastorePb.java:13045)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol.ProtocolMessage.mergeFrom(ProtocolMessage.java:405)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol.ProtocolMessage.mergeFrom(ProtocolMessage.java:422)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol.ProtocolMessage.parseFrom(ProtocolMessage.java:534)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.wrap(DatastoreApiHelper.java:90)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.wrap(DatastoreApiHelper.java:83)
at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.wrapAndCache(FutureWrapper.java:51)
at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:67)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:71)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:32)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl.loadMoreEntities(QueryResultsSourceImpl.java:69)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl.loadMoreEntities(QueryResultsSourceImpl.java:56)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.ensureLoaded(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:156)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.hasNext(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:65)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator$1.get(RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator.java:50)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator$1.get(RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator.java:47)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.QueryExceptionWrappers$1.get(QueryExceptionWrappers.java:51)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.QueryExceptionWrappers$2.get(QueryExceptionWrappers.java:86)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator.hasNext(RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator.java:105)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.LazyResult.resolveAll(LazyResult.java:115)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.LazyResult.size(LazyResult.java:110)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.StreamingQueryResult.size(StreamingQueryResult.java:130)
at guestbook.ProxyServlet.processRequest(ProxyServlet.java:132)
at guestbook.ProxyServlet.doGet(ProxyServlet.java:288)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:97)
```

The code at line 132 in my proxy servlet access a list of entities I retrived from the database. It's this line "System.out.println("from db "+allEventsLst.size());"

My application works when I run a local server. Any ideas???

```
    String fromDateStr = shortDf.format(fromDate);



    Query query = pm.newQuery(Event.class, "date >= fromDate");
      query.declareImports("import java.lang.String");
      query.declareParameters("String fromDate");    

    List<Event> allEventsLst = (List<Event>)query.execute(fromDateStr);

    System.out.println("from db "+allEventsLst.size());

    Map<String, Event> eventMap = new HashMap<String, Event>();

    for (Event e : allEventsLst) {
```

Thanks

Comment: Your dataset grew big enough not to fit in available memory anymore?

Comment: Ok, my bad. The appEngine version was not performing the date filtering properly so it was fetching everything hence the out of memory. The problem is that I keep the date as a String in the entity and I can't change it because of client dependency. How can I get only the entities from db which have date bigger then the date I'm getting in?

Comment: What format is your date in? If it's ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd), you can filter on strings and get the expected result. If not, you're out of luck - you'll have to use mapreduce to replace your date strings with actual dates.

Comment: Fixed it by adding a Date field and sorted on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure but could be that the List is lazy loaded and when you call the size method it has to load all the elements. As your application has been running for awhile it may have enough elements to cause the out of memory problem.

Comment: Maybe its that locally the db is small, and the date test doesn't work so the whole db gets loaded in the appengine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the number of rows that is being returned from your source.  Odds are, there is significantly more rows than normal and your data source doesn't have cursor'ing enabled, so the driver is trying to load all of the rows into memory and then running out.

Comment: It's not at all a big result getting returned. like 10 items.